# webassembly access to curent time

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I want to access date and time in web assembly
can I do this directly from web assembly or should bind it in javascript?

```
 _emscripten_get_now = dateNow
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to C++ or machine assembly language, so I'm deleting those tags.

Comment: @nate-eldredge the base core before converting to wasm is cpp

Comment: @mohamadreza - have you looked at the Emscripten reference API docs? https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/html5.h.html#c.emscripten_date_now